# How can I separate some collections to another server?

Tags: mongodb, clustering, sharding, mongodb-3.2

If my server disk is fulled, I want to move some collections to another server.

Is it possible?

Is there another way from [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/) implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But after moving data to another server, your application must have mean to connect that server when it needs to read/write that DB.Collection.

It is possible even in sharded cluster, I have done that. In that case too, application must have mean to connect that "second" RS or Cluster.

You must give more information, if you need doable solution.

With https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector you can easily replicate single/RS/Cluster to destination...

Comment: I've increased your answer. These days I cannot try your solution. But its turn will come. Thanks!